# Is this enumeration valid, and if so, why?

Tags: c++

```
enum color = {blue, black=3, yellow=3};
```

2 colors have the value 3, is it valid? I thought an enumeration has to have different values.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use both black and yellow in a case statement.

Comment: There's a syntax error. Remove the `=` after `color`: `enum color = {blue, black=3, yellow=3};`.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not uncommon to reuse enumeration values for the sake of backward compatibility. For instance, in version 1 of your library you might have `enum color { blue, black, grey };` and in version 2 you decide to go for american english all the way so you make it `enum color { blue, black, grey, gray = grey };`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's valid in that it's allowed. Probably not a good design though.

As far as why, I'm not sure what answer you are looking for there. If it was not allowed, then it would prevent cases where it made sense to have two enums refer to the same value. (I'm sure I could easily come up with examples where this made sense.)

So if it's a choice between restricting what I can do, or being limited because I'll usually won't want duplicates, then I would have voted for that way it is.

Comment: It doesn't answer the why part of the Q.The part answered here can be just checked by compiling the given code using `-pedantic`.

Comment: @als: I don't know what the designers were thinking but my response did indeed try and answer the question why: Because there could be times where you want two enums with the same value.

Comment: If you compare the timestamp in edit history of the answer and that of my comment you will see that When I commented the answer only said *"It's valid in that it's allowed. Probably not a good design though."* Which obviously didn't answer the *Why?*

Answer (score 2):

The [C++ standard](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf), section 7.2, part 1, requires only that the constant expression be of an integral or enumerated type; there is no requirement for the constant values to be distinct. This gives you additional flexibility at aliasing your constants, if you think it makes your code more expressive. For example,

```
enum color {red=1,green=2,blue=3,max_color=3};

if (myColor > max_color) {/* report an error *}
```

is better than

```
enum color {red=1,green=2,blue=3};

if (myColor > blue) {/* report an error *}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have developed a framework. This framework uses enum for parameterizing

To some reason you are no more happy with an earlier used term.

Just replacing the term would break existing software. You decide to offer old and new terminology (at least for one release cycle)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum color {blue, black=3, yellow=3};

int main()
{

    color a = blue;
    color b = black;
    color c = yellow;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<c<<endl;


        return 0;
}
```

It's not a good idea to make them same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's valid. Because it does not violate language spec. The following is quoted from draft N3242, as you can see in the example, value associated with different enumerator need not be distinct:

```
The identifiers in an enumerator-list are declared as constants, 
and can appear wherever constants are required. An enumeratordefinition
with = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the 
constant-expression. The constant-expression shall be an integral 
constant expression (5.19). If the first enumerator has no initializer,
the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without
an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by
increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one.
[ Example:
enum { a, b, c=0 };
enum { d, e, f=e+2 };
defines a, c, and d to be zero, b and e to be 1, and f to be 3. —end example ]
```